# Overfull \hbox in paragraph at lines 57--63

Tags: formatting, org-mode

I've finally made the move to org-mode from Evernote, I can get simple documents exported via tex to pdf, but i have things like this in there:

```
Create Apache virtual host file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain)
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain1.foo.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1/
</VirtualHost>
```

And every time i try to export, i get `Overfull \hbox (0.54298pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 57--63`

I've tried appending = to the start and end, but still no luck.

I've tried `"<s tab"` which adds `#+BEGIN_SRC` and  `#+END_SRC` tags, but still get the same error.

Any ideas? i have probably 20~ occurrences of this error throughout my notes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a working example it is hard to guess, but is that apache config block being set in a monospace tt font? If so there is no flexibility in the spacing so there is a fixed number of characters that can fit on a line and you are half a character too wide.  You could limit the line length in your source, or you could increase `\textwidth` by .6pt or you could ignore it, or you could set `\hfuzz=.6pt` which would tell tex to ignore it.